# Source data is updating but plot is never updating

Tags: python, bokeh

The source data is updated when changing dropdown menu using the function (filter_source) and can observe the output in the terminal. But the graph is never updating.

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models.widgets import TextInput, Button, Paragraph
from bokeh.layouts import layout
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import Select
from bokeh.layouts import layout
import math

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/austinejose/Desktop/My Files/Work/Newcastle Service Station/2018/Feb_Totals.csv')
df1  = df[df['Department']=='Hot Food']
names = [str(x) for x in df1['Product Name']]
source  = ColumnDataSource(data = df1)

p = figure(x_range = names, plot_height = 500, width = 1000, title = "Sales By Departments",
           toolbar_location = "below")
p.vbar(x = "Product Name", top = "Retail Value", width = 0.9, source = source, color = 'deepskyblue')
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = "white"
p.y_range.start = 0
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = math.pi/4
p.xaxis.axis_label = "Departments"
p.yaxis.axis_label = "Retail Value"
p.axis.minor_tick_in = -3
p.axis.minor_tick_out = 6
p.outline_line_color = "black"

def filter_source(attr, old, new):
    new_source = df[df['Department']==select.value]
    source.data = new_source
    names = [str(x) for x in new_source['Product Name']]

menus = df['Department'].unique().tolist()
select = Select(title = 'Choose Department', options = menus, value = 'Bill Pay')
select.on_change('value', filter_source)

lay_out=layout([[select]])
curdoc().add_root(p)
curdoc().add_root(lay_out)
```

No error messages so far.

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT: Starting with version 1.3, the original code above will work, too*

To be honest I am surprised this is not raising an exception. The `.data` property of an existing CDS can only be set from a plain Python dict, which you can do create with:

```
def filter_source(attr, old, new):
    new_df = df[df['Department']==select.value]
    source.data = ColumnDataSource.from_df(new_df)
```

Edit: It *does* raise an exception to set from a DataFrame, but maybe is hard to notice in the middle of server console output.

Comment: I've made an issue to make this work directly: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/9052

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks very much.